# Is it possible to know the image size in an RDLC report?

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

I'm looking into doing reports using RDLC and have an interesting problem. We want to display a graph on the report and the built-in chart just don't cut it so we generate them as a bitmap instead. Now this works, but to get the best display it would be nice to know the size of the available size on the report. Is it possible to know that in any way?

I could read the RDLC file as XML and try to find something like:

```
  <Image Name="Image1">
    <Source>Database</Source>
    <Value>=First(Fields!MyPicture.Value, "ThisPicture")</Value>
    <MIMEType>image/png</MIMEType>
    <Sizing>FitProportional</Sizing>
    <Top>2.83601cm</Top>
    <Left>0.15875cm</Left>
    <Height>4.43951cm</Height>
    <Width>7.79167cm</Width>
    <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
    <Style>
      <Border>
        <Style>Solid</Style>
      </Border>
    </Style>
  </Image>
```

and use those values and convert them to pixels. Clumsy, but workable.

Comment: What have you tried? AFAIK it's just an XML file which you should be able to read.